# clang error: cannot pass object of non-trivial type 'std::vector<long>' through variadic method; call will abort at runtime [-Wnon-pod-varargs]

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, c++17, clang

I build with gcc，compile success，and run success！
but when i build my repo with clang, i meet compile error！

this is one error,other errors similar

```
./engine/dispatcher.h:74:57: error: cannot pass object of non-trivial type 'std::vector<long>' through variadic method; call will abort at runtime [-Wnon-pod-varargs]
  bool ret = (this->runner->*ins_func[func_i][dtype_i])(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
```

many function calls this code

```
template <class RunnerType>
template <typename... Args>
bool Dispatcher<RunnerType>::dispatcher(const int func_i, const int dtype_i, Args &&...args) {
bool ret = (this->runner->*ins_func[func_i][dtype_i])(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

statement

```
template <typename RunnerType>
class Dispatcher {
 public:
bool (RunnerType::*ins_func[INSTRUCTION_NUM][DTYPE_NUM])(...);
}
```

others related code

```
template <typename RunnerType>
void Dispatcher<RunnerType>::init_instructions_func() {
  ins_func[privpy::func::SAVE][privpy::dtype::INT8] = reinterpret_cast<bool (RunnerType::*)(...)>(
      &RunnerType::template save<int8_t, typename RunnerType::TypeSet::INUMT8>);
  ins_func[privpy::func::SAVE][privpy::dtype::INT16] = reinterpret_cast<bool (RunnerType::*)(...)>(
      &RunnerType::template save<int16_t, typename RunnerType::TypeSet::INUMT16>);
}
```

clang-version：14.0.0 
os：ubuntu20.04

i write a demo to reproduce the problem，show the same error

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

bool (*ins_func)(...);
bool save(int a,vector<long> arr)
{
        cout << a << endl;
        cout <<   " hello " << endl;
        return true;
}
template <typename T, typename... Args>
bool sum_super_cool(T v, Args... args) {
        cout << "pre" << endl;
        bool ret = (*ins_func)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        return ret;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    ins_func = reinterpret_cast<bool (*)(...)>(&save);
    vector<long> arr;
    arr.push_back(123);
    sum_super_cool(1, 2, arr);

    return 0;
}
```

```
root@3e53105276e1:~/test/main# clang++-14 variable_arg.cpp -std=c++17
variable_arg.cpp:17:25: error: cannot pass object of non-trivial type 'std::vector<long>' through variadic function; call will abort at runtime [-Wnon-pod-varargs]
        bool ret = (*ins_func)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
                               ^
variable_arg.cpp:25:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'sum_super_cool<int, int, std::vector<long>>' requested here
    sum_super_cool(1, 2, arr);
    ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: A variadic function (using ...) Is different from variadic templates (Args...). The types you can pass to a variadic function are limited. Forwarding would be odd in this context because you need to pass nothing by value or you need to know more about the types of the arguments.

Comment: @JeffGarrett i supplement my question，write a demo，show the same error，how can i change my code to complile success with clang，use gcc build success and run success。

Comment: You can't simply `reinterpret_cast` a function from one type to another and expect it to work.  The fact that the `g++` generated code 'appears' to work is just coincidence: the code shown exhibits undefined behaviour.

Comment: i change `variadic function pointer` to `function pointer`，and not use `reinterpret_cast`.i run success.But, in my code,if i not use `reinterpret_cast`.i will change too many codes.Does hava any convenience method replace `reinterpret_cast`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not also pass the function as a template parameter:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

bool save(int a, std::vector<long> arr)
{
    std::cout << a << '\n';
    std::cout << " hello \n";
    return true;
}

template <typename T, typename Callable, typename... Args>
bool sum_super_cool(T v, Callable ins_func, Args&&... args)
{
    std::cout << "pre\n";
    return ins_func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::vector<long> arr;
    arr.push_back(123);
    sum_super_cool(1, save, 2, arr);

    return 0;
}
```

This [works fine](https://godbolt.org/z/drnPE836K) without any `reinterpret_cast`ing voodoo. That should almost always be a giant red flag!